# Rails4 Routes public directory on different subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently I have a static webpage and I am working on a Rails4 app to replace that page.

Lets say my current website URL is: `http://www.foo.com`

I have a java app that will look for updates in a specific URL: `http://foo.com/updates/1.1/updateDescriptor.xml` and download some files in that same directory.

Everytime I want to create a new update for my java app, I will use an FTP client and replace the xml and the other files from that directory.

I want to create a public subdomain:
`http://files.foo.com` and put there the updates directory.
So, my java apps will look for: `http://files.foo.com/updates/1.1/updateDescriptor.xml`

The problem is that every java app out there will search in the old URL.
So, how can I redirect it in rails?
I tried:

```
routes.rb <br/>
get '/updates/*all', to: redirect('http://files.foo.pt/updates/%{all}')
```

But, the URL is not well encoded:

```
http://foo.com/updates/1.1/updateDescriptor.xml
```

turns to:

```
http://files.foo.com/updates/1.1%2FupdateDescriptor
```

Which is wrong encoded, and a HTTP 404 results!
Do you guys have any idea that may help me on this?
Thanks,
Nuno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `get '/updates/*version/*file.*format', to: redirect('http://files.foo.pt/updates/%{version}/%{file}.%{format}')`